# What's the difference between "waste time" and "pass time"?

Tags: differences, language-formation

In this sentence" If reading is to accomplish anything more than___time, it must be active. "Should I fill in "wasting" or "passing"? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is mostly one of valuation.  "Wasting time" is negative, while "passing time" is positive.

If you "waste time", you are using up time that could have been used to more benefit, possibly that of other people.  If you "pass time", you are avoiding boredom while spanning time that would be unused for anything.

So, with "wasting" you'd get this meaning:

> If reading is to accomplish anything more than keeping you from accomplishing something useful with your time, it must be active.

and with "passing" you'd get this meaning:

> If reading is to accomplish anything more than entertaining you while you wait for something, it must be active.